# no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Image*’ to ‘const Image&’

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm having some difficulty calling a copy constructor I set up.

```
Image::Image(const Image& img) /* Copy constructor */
{
    this->x = img.x;
    this->y = img.y;
    this->data = img.data;
}
```

I'm trying to call it with `Image input = *new Image(GetInput());`. `GetInput()` returns a `Image*`. Is there a way I can make the arguments match up?

Comment: Did you know that every time you do `*new Image(GetInput())` you leak memory? You dynamically allocate memory to construct an object, dereference the pointer to copy that object, and then you haven't saved the pointer and can't call `delete` to release the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this :

```
Image input = *new Image(GetInput());
```

Results in a instant memory leak because the allocated memory is stored nowhere.

If `GetInput()` does not allocate the returned `Image` every time, you can just do :

```
Image input = *GetInput();
```

Else you'd better go with some smart pointer :

```
std::unique_ptr<Image> input { GetInput() }; // C++11
auto input = std::make_unique<Image>(GetInput()); // C++1y / C++14
```

A far better solution would be to completely avoid the use of any pointer, but I guess this go out of the scope of the actual question ...

Also, if `Image::data` is a dynamically allocated variable, you'll run into a lot of trouble if you simply copy the pointers like you do in your snippet.

Comment: It is the same syntax as for `std::shared_ptr`. If you actually talk about the missing parenthesis after `GetInput`, it's been fixed.

Comment: Yeah, it was the missing parenthesis, I was wondering why such a syntax would be added, but then figured it might be working more like `std::bind` for some reason

Comment: Well [it's almost like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) though.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Turns out my GetInput() segfaults, but this issue's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

`*new Image(....)` is a bad idea because the memory allocated by `new` is immediately leaked. You never `delete` that pointer.

You can probably write:

```
Image *p = GetInput();
Image input(*p);
```

You would have to check the GetInput() function to find out if the returned pointer needs deleting or not; if so, then follow up with a:

```
delete p;
```

Note: make sure `Image` has a correct copy-constructor (check the Rule of Three too).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy the result of `GetInput` into a new variable. You can do that with

```
Image input(*GetInput());
```

However, what happens to the value returned from `GetInput`? The documentation of the function should tell you who owns that object and who's responsibility it is to delete it.

If the caller (that's you) owns the object, you might be better of by just copying the pointer instead of creating a new object:

```
Image *input = GetInput();
```